# Import only library essentials from Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am using Pandas for a Python program. Importing Pandas slows down the load-up a bit, so I am wondering if there's any way to import only the bare essentials by doing `from pandas import x`.

The only functions I am using are:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv
df[""].apply()
df.to_csv("file.csv")
```

Comment: Why would you want to optimize for that? Imports are only executed at the very beginning of your program and just one single time - Is the import really a bottleneck in your workflow?

Comment: @cel I used the csv module before I started with Pandas, and the latter is noticeably slower to load up.